# Does SharePoint 2013 search support stemming?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

In FAST for SharePoint 2010 I think there was a feature known as stemming, where, if you provided a query like "**car**," the system would implicitly also search for "**cars**." I have not been able to get SharePoint 2013 Enterprise search to behave in this way. If I search for a particular form, it seems to only search for that form and not pluralization.

I know that there is also a wildcard search, so I can search for **"car*"** and get results for "**car**" and "**cars**." But this is not ideal because I don't want unrelated results like "**card**," "**cards**," and "**carbohydrates**."

The REST interface seems to have a property called `EnableStemming` (`https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163876.aspx`), but in my experimentation it has no effect on the type or quantity of results returned.

Has anyone gotten stemming to work, or are wildcards intended to be the replacement for stemming in 2013?

**Update**: I have done some more work with this portal, and I found that stemming clearly is available and does work. For example, if I searched for "**test**," SharePoint would find results matching "**tests**," and the hithighlighting would indicate that it was indeed matching on the plural form. I think my problem had to do with the fact that I was running my REST queries anonymously. I have so far been unable to get any stemmed results in that scenario, but I was able to work around the problem by enabling authentication for my REST queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stemming is available in SharePoint 2013 and enabled by default. Stemming is only available on nouns and adjectives in 2013, you can't search on verbs. I.e if you search **car** search will return the results for **Cars** But if you search for **Run** it will only return the Run results not for **Ran**.

Read More over here.

http://stevemannspath.blogspot.com/2013/04/stemming-in-sharepoint-2013-search.html

An work around he suggest OR operator.
http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2015/03/word-stemming-in-sharepoint-2013-search.html

Comment: I had a look at azure search service API. Is it not possible to utilize that with SharePoint search? For example something like the demo shown here - https://alice.unearth.ai/